# Angular2 is there a way to get a list of routes out of the Router?

Tags: routes, angular

What I would like to do is dynamically build my navigation by iterating through a list of configured routes in Angular2. I cannot seem to find anywhere in the Router where I can access the configured routes. Has anyone tried anything like this?

I looked into the `Router`'s `registry` property but it doesn't seem to have anything usable.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <h1>Routing Example</h1>
        <div>
            <div>
                <b>Main menu: </b>
                <a [router-link]="['Home']">Home</a> | 
                <a [router-link]="['One']">One</a> | 
                <a [router-link]="['Two']">Two</a>

                <!-- 
                  // I would rather do something like this:
                  <a *ng-for="#route of router.routes" [router-link]="['route.name']">{{ route.name }}</a>
                -->

            </div>
            <div>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
    { path: '/home', as: 'Home', component: Main },
    { path: '/one', as: 'One', component: One },
    { path: '/two', as: 'Two', component: Two },
])
export class MyApp {
    constructor(public location: Location, public router: Router){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I also needed to dynamically generate links. As I understand it, problem is that router doesn't have methods to generate links other then manually putting them in `[router-link]`. Yet... [but they plan to add them](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5318#issuecomment-157474890). There's [lot of features](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3A%22comp%3A%20router%22%20label%3A%22type%3A%20feature%22) in queue for the router, hopefully they add them soon (;

For now I made this work - I put routerConfig outside the decorator, so I can use it in this component (and possibly others if I export it):

```
let routeConfig = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Intro', component: IntroRouteComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  ...
  { path: '/projects', name: 'Projects', component: ProjectsRouteComponent },
  { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutRouteComponent },
];

@Component({
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [],
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <a (click)="back()" *ngIf="prevRoute">{{ prevRoute }}</a>
    <a (click)="forward()" *ngIf="nextRoute">{{ nextRoute }}</a>
  `,
})
@RouteConfig(routeConfig)
export class AppComponent {
  private nextRoute: any;
  private prevRoute: any;

  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this._router.subscribe(route => {
      let i = routeConfig.findIndex(r => r.path === ('/' + route));
      this.prevRoute = routeConfig[i - 1] ? routeConfig[i - 1].name : false;
      this.nextRoute = routeConfig[i + 1] ? routeConfig[i + 1].name : false;
    });
  }

  back() {
    this._router.navigate(Array(this.prevRoute));
  }
  forward(): any {
    this._router.navigate(Array(this.nextRoute));
  }

}
```