# How to list / output all routes in @Routes in my Angular2 App

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a quick question. I'm currently looking through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html but I was wondering, in my Angular2's `main.ts` I have my routes defined thus:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/about-me', component: AboutMeComponent },
    { path: '/food', component: FoodComponent },
    { path: '/photos', component: PhotosComponent },
    { path: '/technology', component: TechnologyComponent },
    { path: '/blog', component:Blogomponent },
])
```

Now in a component elsewhere I import the Router class. In my component (or the component template) I would like to loop through all my routes defined or just be able to access them. Is there a built in way to do this? Like some function that returns an object array? Here is a crude idea of what I want...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ms-navigation',
    templateUrl: 'src/navigation/navigation.template.html',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})

export class NavigationComponent {
    constructor(private router:Router) {   
        // what can I do here to get an array of all my routes?
        console.log(router.routes); ????
    }
}
```

Comment: This user [factored it out of the decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096685/angular2-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-routes-out-of-the-router).

Comment: So I can access an array of the routes doing `this.router.config` (no browser errors), however, this throws the following typescript error in terminal ~ `error TS2341: Property 'config' is private and only accessible within class 'Router'.` Now if only we can debug this error or find some other clues to help us get there ...

Answer (score 61):

Here is a better version which will list **all** possible *routes* (fixed according to comments):

```
import { Router, Route } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.printpath('', this.router.config);
}

printpath(parent: string, config: Route[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
    const route = config[i];
    console.log(parent + '/' + route.path);
    if (route.children) {
      const currentPath = route.path ? `${parent}/${route.path}` : parent;
      this.printpath(currentPath, route.children);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is useful but it's a little misleading. To get "all possible routes", you need to remove the `&& r.path` in the last if statement. I had child routes which were in a module with a default empty string route which caused all the child routes to be skipped because they were nested under the empty string route.

Comment: In Angular5, I only get the top-level routes with this one, because children are undefined. How would I get all possible routes (including children) as opposed to all loaded routes?

Comment: Tested on Angular 9. Works okay apart from where you have lazy loaded routes (tested using the promise syntax i.e.  `loadChildren: () => import('./pathToModule/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)`). In that case I think it would be ideal to add another condition check `if ('_loadedConfig' in route) {}` in which you can access child routes from `route['_loadedConfig'].routes`

Comment: does not work @rey_coder route['_loadedConfig'] returns undefined. _loadedConfig is not part of the public API

Comment: Yes, @THEAMAZING and I captured that in the comment....i.e it doesn't work if the route is lazy loaded. thus the 'loadedConfig' property check condition to ensure value is defined. Unlesss on your end it also doesnt work for all routes.

Comment: For anyone using lazy loaded routes, in Angular 14, `_loadedConfig.routes` has been replaced with `_loadedRoutes` on the Route.

Comment: @Jay Did you figure out how to get ALL routes from all routers? Can we specify which router to pull routes from? I am using Angular 15.

Comment: Angular 16 this does not load the children

Answer (score 47):

Apparently there is a very compact way to do it:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('configured routes: ', this.router.config);
}
```

Comment: This only works module-wise. If you are having more than one module in your application, you will only get the routes according to the module you are executing the commans above.

Comment: Doesn't work when using lazy-loading

Answer (score 16):

If you only need the route paths as strings, you can find them by iterating over your `Router` object's `config` array.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < this.router.config.length; i++) {
        var routePath:string = this.router.config[i].path;
        console.log(routePath);
    }
```

Comment: This only shows the top level routes. Anand Rockzz's answer is much better

Answer (score 13):

I am using this comp. to get all routes in angular 9

```
import { Compiler, Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './sitemap.component.html'
})
export class SiteMapComponent implements OnInit {

  public urls: string[] = [];
  constructor(private _router: Router, private compiler: Compiler, private injector: Injector) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.config.forEach(i => {
      this.getPaths(i);
    })
  }

  getPaths(route: Route, parent: string = '') {
    if (route.redirectTo) {
      return;
    }
    if (route.children) {
      route.children.forEach(i => {
        this.getPaths(i, parent + route.path);
      });
    }
    else if (route.loadChildren) {
      (<any>this._router).configLoader.load(this.injector, route).subscribe(i => {
        i.routes.forEach(j => {
          this.getPaths(j, parent + route.path)
        });
      });
    }
    else if (route.path != null) {
      this.setPath(route.path, parent);
    }
  }
  setPath(path, parent) {
    let fullPath: string;
    if (path != null) {
      if (parent) {
        fullPath = `/${parent}/${path}`;
      }
      else {
        fullPath = `/${path}`
      }
    }
    this.urls.push(fullPath)
  }
}
```

**Update Angular 14**:
<strike>configLoader.load</strike>

`(<any>this._router).configLoader.loadChildren`

**Update Angular 17**:
<strike>configLoader.loadChildren</strike>

`(<any>this._router).navigationTransitions.configLoader.loadChildren`

Answer (score 7):

This comes as an extension to [@Anand Rockzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234110/anand-rockzz)'s answer.

Was written for Angular 6.0 and list all possible routes including the **lazy** ones (https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules):

**UPDATED**

As [@Daniel B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447173/daniel-b) mentioned:

> [...] this no longer works with Angular 8.0

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadedRouterConfig } from '@angular/router/src/config';

printPaths(parent: string, routes: Route[]) {
    const getFullPath = (path?: string) => {
        if (path) {
            return parent + '/' + path;
        }

        return parent;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        const route = routes[i];
        const fullPath = getFullPath(route.path);

        console.log(parent + '/' + route.path, route.component);

        if (route.children /*&& route.children.length > 0*/) {
            this.printPaths(fullPath, route.children);
        }

        if (route.loadChildren && route.loadChildren.length > 0) {
            var routerConfig = <LoadedRouterConfig>(<any>route)['_loadedConfig'];
            if (routerConfig) {
                this.printPaths(fullPath, routerConfig.routes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The modification you've made has undefined in every routerConfig. I'm using latest Angular (7.0.4)

Comment: Forgot to mention that this should not be used in production.
The core issue might be that the code is being minified and there will no longer be a variable called `_loadedConfig`.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same solution with lazy loaded routes, is there an alternative solution if the `_loadedConfig` is minified for production use?

Comment: @phanf Actually tested this code in production mode and it works.

Comment: @phanf Can you provide an example of how you setup the routes?

Comment: @AdrianPaul After reviewing my source, I also tested in production mode, your example does work with lazy loaded routes on Angular 6+.as you stated. Thanks!

Comment: @phanf Cool! Good to hear that! :)

Comment: @Mike Sorry, but haven't tested this in a greater major version.

Comment: Just a comment to inform people that this no longer works with Angular 8.0.

Comment: What are the alternatives now in Angular 8?

Comment: Maybe this is no longer working in Angular 8 due to the fact that `LoadedRouterConfig` is "moved" to an untyped file _@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js_. Will update the code after I'll get a working solution.

Comment: @AdrianPaul it's been a year, any luck?

Comment: @AdrianPaul any luck?

Comment: Unfortunattely (for this thread) I moved to different stacks and didn't had the chance to revisit this. But I sense that the _route_ used for extracting the _routerConfig_ can be cast to `any` and it will do the magic. Also check for existing variables inside the _@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js_ file. And also note that this is a hack.

Answer (score 3):

For @angular version 2.00 I was able to find a list of the children through the routeConfig property.

Here is an example of my component. 
Note, I'm accessing the children via the 'parent' property as the component is actually one of the children as I'm rendering it in the child router-outlet.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Route, ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'list',
    template: require('./list.component.html')
})
export class ListComponent {
    children = new Array<RouteLink>();

    constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        for (let child of activatedRoute.parent.routeConfig.children) {
            if (child.path && child.data["breadcrumb"]) {
                this.children.push(new RouteLink(child.path, child.data["breadcrumb"]));
            }
        }
    }
}

export class RouteLink {
    constructor(private path: string, private name: string) {  }
}
```

Comment: does not work..

Answer (score 2):

I’ve created a util function based on the [answer of @OMANSAK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154129/9740071).
Tested with Angular 12 and lazy loaded modules.

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Route } from '@angular/router';

const routerUrls: string[] = [];

async function getPaths(router: Router, injector: Injector, route: Route, parent: string = ''): Promise<void> {
   if (route.redirectTo) {
       return;
   }
   if (route.children) {
       for (const childRoute of route.children) {
           await getPaths(router, injector, childRoute, parent + route.path);
       }
   } else if (route.loadChildren) {
       const lazyConfig = await router['configLoader'].load(injector, route).toPromise();
       for (const childRoute of lazyConfig.routes) {
           await getPaths(router, injector, childRoute, parent + route.path);
       }
   } else if (route.path !== null) {
       if (route.path !== '') {
           routerUrls.push(parent ? `/${parent}/${route.path}` : `/${route.path}`);
       } else {
           routerUrls.push(parent ? `/${parent}` : '');
       }
   }
}

/**
 * Returns routes of the app via the Angular Router.
 *
 * Important: The fallback route in the app module (path: "**")
 * has to be the last element in your top level app-routing-module.
 *
 * @param router Angular Router
 * @param injector Angular Injector
 * @returns Routes of the app
*/
export async function getAllPaths(router: Router, injector: Injector): Promise<string[]> {
   const topLevelRoutes = router.config.slice(
       0,
       router.config.findIndex((route) => route.path === '**') ?? router.config.length - 1
   );
   for (const i of topLevelRoutes) {
       await getPaths(router, injector, i);
   }
   return routerUrls;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Angular 9+, you can look at a component that has a Router injected, via the browser console:

```js
window.ng.getComponent(document.querySelector('app-employee-overview')).router.config[0].children
```

Answer (score 0):

You run into issues using this solution if you have Lazy routes. I made a simple bash command to show the routing information:

```
cd /path/to/app 
for r in $(find src -name "*.routes.ts"); do 
  echo $r; grep "path:\|component:\|loadChildren:" $r; 
done
```

Comment: Great! Now, how did you run it in your Angular app?

Comment: this is a build script, not what you are looking for. @rey_coder

Answer (score 0):

A small update for @Vasco's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569936/how-to-list-output-all-routes-in-routes-in-my-angular2-app/45492930#answer-70588011) for Angular 14

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Route } from '@angular/router';

let routerUrls: { path: string; component: any }[] = [];

async function getRoutes(
    router: Router,
    injector: Injector,
    route: Route,
    parent: string = ''
): Promise<void> {
    if (route.redirectTo) {
        return;
    }
    if (route.children) {
        for (const childRoute of route.children) {
            await getRoutes(
                router,
                injector,
                childRoute,
                parent ? `${parent}/${route.path}` : route.path
            );
        }
    } else if (route.loadChildren) {
        const lazyConfig = await router['configLoader'].loadChildren(injector, route).toPromise();
        for (const childRoute of lazyConfig.routes) {
            await getRoutes(router, injector, childRoute, parent + route.path);
        }
    } else if (route.path !== null) {
        if (route.path !== '') {
            routerUrls.push({
                path: parent ? `/${parent}/${route.path}` : `/${route.path}`,
                component: route.component,
            });
        } else {
            routerUrls.push({ path: parent ? `/${parent}` : '', component: route.component });
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns routes of the app via the Angular Router.
 *
 * Important: The fallback route in the app module (path: "**")
 * has to be the last element in your top level app-routing-module.
 *
 * @param router Angular Router
 * @param injector Angular Injector
 * @returns Routes of the app
 */
export async function getAllRoutes(
    router: Router,
    injector: Injector
): Promise<{ path: string; component: any }[]> {
    routerUrls = [];
    const topLevelRoutes = router.config.slice(
        0,
        router.config.findIndex((route) => route.path === '**') ?? router.config.length - 1
    );
    for (const i of topLevelRoutes) {
        await getRoutes(router, injector, i);
    }
    return routerUrls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference: getting routes when using lazy components is difficult in run time, but thanks to the popularity of frameworks like Scully for the jamsstack we can now use guess-parser to list our routes during build time.

This is a build script, so it may or may not be what you want.

> parseAngularRoutes(tsconfig: string) - Extracts the routes of an Angular application. As arguments the function accepts path to the tsconfig.json file of the project.
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/guess-parser

Here's a concept to hook this into the build;

Install the dev dep. `npm i guess-parser --save-dev`. Add a file and add something along the lines of this:

```js
var guess = require('.\\node_modules\\guess-parser\\dist\\guess-parser\\index.js');
console.log(guess.parseAngularRoutes('.\tsconfig.json')); // Output for now, but you could save this as json in your /dist/assets folder and serve it
```

Then run `ng build` and `node output-routes.js` and see the results roll in after some time:

```js
[
  ...
  {
    path: '/general/overview',
    lazy: true,
    modulePath: '[REDACTED]\\src\\app\\modules\\general\\general.module.ts',
    parentModulePath: '[REDACTED]\\src\\app\\app.module.ts'
  },
  {
    path: '/general/products',
    lazy: true,
    modulePath: '[REDACTED]\\src\\app\\modules\\general\\general.module.ts',
    parentModulePath: '[REDACTED]\\src\\app\\app.module.ts'
  },
  ...
]
```

This could be hooked up in your build process after building.
This could also be hooked into file watchers, see:
[Hook into angular-cli build watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364234/hook-into-angular-cli-build-watch)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to look at the available route by importing into a component.

assign your routes to a constant like below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'asd',
        component: asdComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'ar',
        component: arComponent
    }
];
```

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);

here you will be able to export the routes

import the **const routing**

```
import { routing }        from './app.routing';
export class AppComponent {
   route=routing;
   /// route.providers is an array which internally contains the list of routes provided
   console.log(route.providers);
}
```

***this is just to find the available routes. not recommendable to implement logic based on this***

Comment: #1 do not import appRoutes, use dependency injection with Router. Also providers is not part of the Routes.