# Getting Router config for lazy loaded module in Angular 2 Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to get Router `config` for lazy loaded module routes in Angular 2 Router?

When I log config on router object, only available routes from the module which has already been loaded are logged,

```
 export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private router: Router){
     console.log(router.config);
   } 
 }
```

**router config**

[image]

I understand since routes inside Lazy loaded modules are resolved at runtime, hence the config are not available. But it restricts us to get configuration data.

Is there a way in which we may get Route data from within the lazy loaded module without loading the module? Or define all routes in start and load the modules lazily?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fp2MmASTwE03gn6acf0p?p=preview)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I mean you said it! Just declare routes in your code, export them from routing module, and import them where you need them. It's not as nice as accessing them as a property of router, but it works.

Comment: If anyone is looking for another way of doing it. check my comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492930/4989448) answer.

Answer (score -3):

**use preloadingStrategy.**

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
 appRoutes,
 {
  enableTracing: true, // <-- debugging purposes only
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
 }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure you read this before answering to ensure good quality answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer