# Defining relative routing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

**Update**

I changed `forRoot` with `forChild` according to the answers.

So, basically I have to issues, let this be a submodule,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ARoutingModule,
    BModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppsComponent, ...],
  exports: [
    AppsComponent, ...
  ]
})
export class AModule { }
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppsComponent, ...],
  exports: [
    AppsComponent, ...
  ]
})
export class BModule { }
```

So `AModule` is being imported by the root module and both modules, `AModule` and `BModule` shall define their own routes, something like

```
// ./A/A-Routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'A',//<-- this shall route to www.site.com/A
   component: AComponent
  }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class ARoutingModule { }
```

and in SubSub I have

```
// ./A/B/B-Routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'B', //<-- this shall route to www.site.com/A/B
   component: BComponent,

   ]
  }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class BRoutingModule { }
```

Is this possible? When using a [path printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569936/how-to-list-output-all-routes-in-routes-in-my-angular2-app), I can get the sub-routes, but not the subsub routes (i.e. B). And can I define the routes in B without knowing the path before that? so define `B` without knowing `A`

```
www.site.com/something/else
```

define routes for `else` without knowing `something`?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yureye) example, `main` works, but the `Subs` don't...

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot([])` is used for routing only in the root module of the application. For using routes in other modules, use `RouterModule.forChild([])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you'll have to fix to make it work properly.

1. You'll have to add an opening route for your `SubModule` which will be a Lazy Loaded Module. You'll do this in your main-routing.module.ts file

---

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'sub',
      loadChildren: './sub/sub.module#SubModule'
    }]
  }
];
```

2. You'll then create a module named `SubModule` and the `SubRoutingModule` will act as a routing module for this `SubModule`. You'll declare your Sub1Component and Sub2Component here:

---

```
import { Sub1Component, Sub2Component } from './sub.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SubRoutingModule } from './sub-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Sub1Component, Sub2Component],
  imports: [SubRoutingModule]
})
export class SubModule { }
```

So now your routes will change to :

```
<a routerLink="/main/sub/sub1">Sub1</a> | 
<a routerLink="/main/sub/sub2">Sub2</a>
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-with-complex-module-hierarchy-eg?file=src/app/main/main.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I need to have multiple routing files at different locations.

Comment: There's a serious architectural issue with your Current Implementation. Can you please share a more concrete example of your modules and probably a minimal stackblitz sample replicating your issue?

Comment: Stackblitz example in the op.

Comment: @rst, please go through my updated answer. Hopefully this should help you achieve what you're trying to.

Answer (score 1):

Change `forRoot` to `forChild` in `SubSubRoutingModule`

```
// ./Sub/subsub/SubSub-Routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'subsub', //<-- this shall route to www.site.com/sub/subsub
   component: SubSubComponent,
   ]
  }
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], //<-- change here
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SubSubRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: That works, but `SubSub` (I changed it in the OP to A and B, thought that was more clearer) get routet to the root, i.e. `/subsub` instead of `/Sub/subsub`

Comment: You should implement with Lazy Module. Look at this demo for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcerdo

Comment: I have added a stackblitz example

Comment: Here is the modified version of your demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3mjttd

Comment: That's exactly what I was Looking for! Excellent