# Angular 8 - How can I build a dynamic menu with all routes in my angular project?

Tags: angular, dynamic, menu, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I'm using loadChildren to organize my routes, like this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'cadastros', loadChildren: () => import('./cadastros/cadastros.module').then((m) => m.CadastrosModule) },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**cadastros-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'geral', loadChildren: () => import('./geral/geral.module').then((m) => m.GeralModule) },
      { path: 'geo', loadChildren: () => import('./geo/geo.module').then((m) => m.GeoModule) },
      { path: 'pgv', loadChildren: () => import('./pgv/pgv.module').then((m) => m.PgvModule) }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CadastrosRoutingModule {}
```

I'd like to build a dynamic menu, so I try to use this:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log('routers', this.router.config)
  }
```

this is the result:
[console.log(this.router.config)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pjBx.png)

But I cannot access the `loadChildren` to get all routes... How can I get all routes to build a dynamic menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list / output all routes in @Routes in my Angular2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569936/how-to-list-output-all-routes-in-routes-in-my-angular2-app)

Comment: @Zze I looked at this topic yesterday but I using Angular 8 with lazyLoaded, so I can't access a children routes... Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

After to search, I found a solution for lazyLoaded, it's called: **'preloaded'**

https://angular.io/guide/router#preloading-background-loading-of-feature-areas

Now I loaded all modules async and I has all routes. But this isn't perfomatic, so I going back to my old way to create this menu.

Comment: Can you please update this answer with the code you applied incase that angular link dies in future