Angular multilanguage route for default language
I'm building an angular website with SSR support and multilanguage. I'm building an EN, FR and DE version.
Everything works but I was wondering if I can make the default language (en in my case) have the route mywebsite.com and not mywebsite.com/en
Also, I have some files such as sitemap and robot.txt that are being produced under mywebsite.com/en/robot.txt and mywebsite.com/en/sitemap.xml. How can I force them to be exported under the root folder (mywebsite.com/robot.txt and mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml respectively)
Thank you!

Create you own dynamic routes. If there is no lang in URL then use the default one. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394946/1817690 may help you.
