# Angular 15 Router - get children of specific route

Tags: angular-router

I have gone through many articles but cannot find a way of getting children routes of a specific route.
The closest example I was able to find is this:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569936/how-to-list-output-all-routes-in-routes-in-my-angular2-app)

However, nothing works in Angular 15. Any idea how to get a list of children routes in Angular 15?

Thanks